how can i set global backgroundimage for tab.screens in react-native?
okay, so i have an app, thats skeleton is a tab.navigator. currently each of the tab.screen have their own backgroundimage using the <ImageBackground>, but when i swipe between the tabs its rather ugly to see the borders between the 2 backgroundimages (they're gradients) and to see that each tab.screen has its own background. here is the navigator:
     <NavigationContainer >
        <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarPosition= 'bottom'
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            header: ({scene}) => <CustomHeader currentTab={scene.route.name} />,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
              let iconName;
              if (route.name === 'Tab1') {
                iconName = focused ? 'school' : 'school-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Tab2') {
                iconName = focused ? 'newspaper' : 'newspaper-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Tab3') {
                iconName = focused ? 'people' : 'people-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Tab4') {
                iconName = focused ? 'library' : 'library-outline';
              }
              return <Icon name={iconName} size={22} color={color} />;
            },
            animationEnabled: true,
            swipeEnabled,
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={UtilsStack} options={{ tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: focused ? themeColors.tabBarActiveTintColor : themeColors.tabBarInactiveColor, }} numberOfLines={1}>
              Tab1
            </Text>)}} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={HomeStack} options={{ tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: focused ? themeColors.tabBarActiveTintColor : themeColors.tabBarInactiveColor, }} numberOfLines={1}>
              Tab2
            </Text>)}} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab3" component={EventStack} options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: focused ? themeColors.tabBarActiveTintColor : themeColors.tabBarInactiveColor, }} numberOfLines={1}>
              Tab3
            </Text> )}} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Tab4" component={EduStack} options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: focused ? themeColors.tabBarActiveTintColor : themeColors.tabBarInactiveColor, }} numberOfLines={1}>
              Tab4
            </Text> )}} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>

i tried wrapping the entire thing with an ImageBackground with various approaches and styling (position, display, zIndex...), but it doesnt seem to work. the best result i got was a white background and thats all.
Im trying to set 1 singular backgroundimage for the whole app, and i imagine only the contents (with transparent backgrounds ofc) moving in front of it. If it works with the background, im planning on doing roughly the same with the header. Any help is greatly appriciated!!! ;)
